# Microsoft App Store: Silent installation requires elevated permission, but this is not disclosed in the Description

Tags: windows-store, software-distribution, microsoft-store

I like to submit my app to the Microsoft App Store, but it fails validation because of this error:

> The product failed to install through the Store. Silent installation
> requires elevated permission, but this is not disclosed in the
> Description.

Yes, the app needs admin permissions in order to install. This is also valid for a silent installation. I described this in the "Properties" -> "Notes for certification". But this seems to be the wrong place?

I cannot find a field "Description" as mentioned in the validation error message.

Does someone know how I get this app validated? The error message is not really helpful :-(

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to edit the application data in **Store listing** -> *Edit for all languages* -> **Description**.

I wrongly assumed that this error is something technical ( failed to install... ). But updating the store entries seemed to fix the issues and validation went fine.